# Add ipv6 static route without subnet nmcli

Tags: ipv6, nmcli

What is nmcli command to implement the following:

```
ip -6 r add 2a00:xxxx:xxxx::1 dev eth0
```

[RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html#sec-Configuring_Static_Routes_Using_nmcli) insists on using network specification but I can't produce another working

```
ip -6 r add 2a00:xxxx:xxxx::1 ????????
```

command to be able to satisfy nmcli sample.